# Powershell: Get return result from Powershell Script called from Within other PS Script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, return-value

**Background:**
I have a powershell script:`script1` that takes in a `sourceDirectory` and two destinations (call them `dest1Directory` and `dest2Directory`).

The sourceDirectory is structured like this:

> \Source\dest1\STUFF1

and

> \Source\dest2\STUFF2

`script1` calls another script:`script2`, `foreach` STUFF (so `script2` may be run 10 times for example), providing `script2` with the necessary destination parameter, which creates backups of all of the contents "STUFF" is replacing on `dest1Directory` and `dest2Directory`, and then copies all of STUFF to the corresponding destination.

`Script1`:

```
foreach ($folder in $STUFF1)
{           
& $script2 -stuffParameter $folder -destDrive $dest1Directory -backUpDrive $BackUpDirectory
}
```

**The issue I'm having is:**

I'm calling `script1` from a visual studio website and would like `script2` to output all of the backup directory paths it creates so I have references to them for later. I have tried this inside of `script2`:

```
$returnRollBackObj = New-Object Object
Add-Member -memberType NoteProperty -name "RollBackLocation" -value $folderobj -inputObject $returnRollBackObj
return $returnRollBackObj
```

But it doesn't seem to return the objects since they are subscript calls. I don't know how to return an undefined number of these objects from `script1` so I'm at a loss. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any uncaptured output is returned in Powershell.

So something like

```
return $returnRollBackObj
```

is equivalent to

```
$returnRollBackObj
return
```

So, since script2 is returning these objects, as long as these objects are not captured in script1, they will be returned by script1 as well. So you not have to do anything about "returning undefined number of objects"

Try running the scripts from console first, to see if you are getting the intended behaviour.

Comment: I figured as much but when I tried it didn't work as expected. I have `script1` calling `script2` with uncaptured returns, however only the one return statement from `script1` outputs to my console. There is a bunch of `Write-Host/Write-Warning` output that works fine from `script2` however.

Comment: Sorry I did not think it was necessary to include this: I have another object containing a log location being returned from `script1` (and this works correctly)

Answer (score 2):

How's your IIS setup?

Just thinking , if you hve eimpersonation on, tha it might not have access to the second script's location due to the double hop issue.

Something else that may help is the transcript functionality. Add a start-transcript at the top of yu script/code and you'll get a dump of everything, comands and output (inc. Errors and warnings).

**Edit:**

Just realised your not assigning the returned values from script2 to aaything in script1.

You may need something like this:

$ret = & $script2 ...

Do something with $ret...

OR put it in an array
$ret = @()

For loop...

$temp = & $script2 ...
$ret = $ret + $temp

Then return $ret after the for loop.

Matt

Comment: Both good ideas, however this is happening when I test it through a powershell command prompt (and the second script is definitely running correctly, besides the output), and I actually have a transcript running, however it doesn't help me with this issue.

Comment: I don't think running from the command prompt negates a double hop issue, i would expect it to work. That said i notice you're not doing anything with the returned variable. I edited my response to show that.

Comment: I will try that, but I figured the returns from script2 would propagate up. Maybe not :). Thanks for the sample

Comment: they would be outputted on stdout. I'll format it when not on my phone. Matt

Comment: I ended up changing something and it worked. I think I was just defining my return objects incorrectly in script2. Thanks for all of your help, but I actually got it working without handling the script2 return objects.